# Disable ActiveRecord parameter filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Rails 6 and it's automatically filtering columns on my ActiveRecord models that have the word `token` in them. I appreciate that, but these columns are not sensitive.

I've searched around but cannot find how I can permit these fields from being displayed in my console or logs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, when you create a new Rails app [this template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb.tt) will be used to create an initializer called `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`.  You can edit the `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters` values that are configured in this file.  You'll need to restart the app after making changes.

Rather than just remove `:token` from the list, you might want to change that to `:authenticity_token` so that you still filter out the Rails authenticity token.

Comment: Thank you! If I do want it to filter out other things with the name `*token` is there a way I can whitelist those specific columns so that they're not filtered?

Comment: I think you could do this but it wouldn't be with a simple whitelist.  You'd have to write a regular expression or use a Proc to manage the filtering.  The filtering is handled by the [`ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter` class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/parameter_filter.rb).  The comments there have some more info.

Comment: A minor point but you should also restart the rails console if you want to see changes there too.